# getMethod is caching and cause a memory leak

Tags: java, class, reflection, memory-leaks

I am using an automatic generated Java class for executing a special method. Because of this i have to invoke the method by reflection.

This execution is triggered by a Swing Thread, because the method (invoked from the "unknown" class) is updating a UI Element. Every execution of a new Thread is searching for a Method in the class by calling

```
Class {
...
public Method[] getMethods() throws SecurityException
...
}
```

The logic of getMethods, caches the element, but i do not know why. A Profiler shows me, that Method obejcts are floating the memory.

I can disable the method caching of Java by setting the system property "sun.reflect.noCaches", but my application became incredible slow, after i changed these property.

**Question:**
I could implement my own caching algorithm, before i try to get the method from the class. But the project i am working is very big and we have multiple reflection calls.

What can solve these problem?

Which cirumstances can trigger these memory leak (wrong classloader,...)?

The project is running under Linux using Java 1.5

Comment: Could you use `getMethod(String, Class[])` instead? It might reduce the number of cached method objects if you aren't using all of them.

Comment: No, because the parameters are not known directly. Only the name is known. The parameters are somwhow calculated magically.

Comment: It is excessive use of available memory which is not the same like a memory leak. Or do you get OOME and these cached objects are still present when it occurs?

Comment: @Markus, you have more than ten questions without an accepted answer. ;)

Comment: @Peter what would you do, if no question solved the question? Would you accept a question after 1 week to be charitable?

Comment: @Markus, a few questions without decent answers is bad luck. However at some point you have to wonder if you are asking clear, answerable questions and following up on answers so they are acceptable. I would seriously consider upgrading your JVM as there have been a lot of improvements over the years. I noticed a real difference between Java 6 update 18 and 26.

Comment: Updating the VM would be expensive for the company, because this has to be tested and shipped to the customer, but i will try to test it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. First thing, the cache that it uses is a [SoftReference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html), so the cached methods will be removed before an OOME ever occurs.
2. If you still want to remove it, just call the `clearCachesOnClassRedefinition()` method after every call to `getMethods(..)`; you will have to use reflection as the method is private.

Comment: +1 for linking to SoftReference (so obviously no mem leak here)

Comment: it should not cause OOME, but this info should be helpful to performance tune

Comment: In the end we get a OOME and the profiler shows a lot of Method objects. I will check the profiling state again in detail.

Comment: @Markus Lausberg Please do this. It is very hard to believe that there is a memory leak, since code is public and widely used. And it is very likely that these SoftReferences are the reasons why you think it is leaking. But nevertheless..let us know about checking profile details again.

Comment: The Profiler (netBeans) showed an incorrect stack. JProfiler did not showed cached MEthod objects. So the table with the cached objects were wrong.